# Don't understand one particular normal distribution notation from opaper Stochastic Variational Deep Kernel Learning, help needed

Tags: regression, neural-networks, normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, kernel-trick

I'm in progress working with paper "[Stochastic Variational Deep Kernel Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00336.pdf)" NIPS 2016

and I have the problem with understanding the meaning of this normal distribution notation from ***part 2 Background***:

> in regression, one could model y(x)|f(x) ∼ **N (y(x);f(x), σ2*I)**

Can you please explain, what does **;** mean and why **y(x);** is added to the notation of normal distribution in this notation and how I should understand the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means $E(y)=f(x)$, $Var(y)=\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$. For example a simple linear regression $y=a x +b+\epsilon,\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$  can also be represented as $y \sim N(ax+b,\sigma^2)$

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, I still don't get why the authors write N (**y(x);**.....). For me this adding of **y(x);** for Normal distribution is unclear

Comment: $N(y(x);mean,var)$ means $y(x) \sim N(mean,var)$, it's just a notation convention

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much, @Haotian Chen